# hyperlink that calls data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a page with a hyperlinks that when clicked will display all the records in the table with a reminder date that is within the current week (Sun-Sat) however by defaul all reminders for the current day are showing. Thanks for your help!

```
// not sure how to create the link for 'Week'
<li><a href="/backend/followup/followup.php">Today</a></li> // default page 
<li><a href="/backend/followup/followup.php?reminder=">Week</a></li>
```

Here is what I have so far and I'm not sure how to put this all together so that by default all reminders for today show up, but if hyperlink 'Week' is clicked only those results show up

```
$today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today'));
$week = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last sunday'));

 $query = "SELECT * FROM contacttodo,contacts WHERE contacttodo.contacts_id = contacts.ID AND contacttodo.reminder = '$today' ORDER BY contacttodo.reminder ASC";

$query = "SELECT * FROM contacttodo,contacts WHERE contacttodo.contacts_id = contacts.ID AND contacttodo.reminder BETWEEN '$week' AND '$week' + INTERVAL 6 DAY ORDER BY contacttodo.reminder ASC";
```

UPDATE- This is working (except for 'lastweek'):

```
if($_GET['reminder'] == 'lastweek') {
$lastweek = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last sunday'));
$query = "SELECT * FROM contacttodo,contacts WHERE contacttodo.contacts_id = contacts.ID AND contacttodo.reminder BETWEEN '$lastweek' AND '$lastweek' - INTERVAL 6 DAY ORDER BY contacttodo.reminder ASC"; 
} 

elseif 

($_GET['reminder'] == 'thisweek') {     
$thisweek = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last sunday'));     
$query = "SELECT * FROM contacttodo,contacts WHERE contacttodo.contacts_id = contacts.ID AND contacttodo.reminder BETWEEN '$thisweek' AND '$thisweek' + INTERVAL 6 DAY ORDER BY contacttodo.reminder ASC"; 
} 

elseif 

($_GET['reminder'] == 'nextweek') {     
$nextweek = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next sunday'));     
$query = "SELECT * FROM contacttodo,contacts WHERE contacttodo.contacts_id = contacts.ID AND contacttodo.reminder BETWEEN '$nextweek' AND '$nextweek' + INTERVAL 6 DAY ORDER BY contacttodo.reminder ASC"; 
} 

elseif 

($_GET['reminder'] == 'thismonth') {     
$thismonth = date('Y-m-d');     
$query = "SELECT * FROM contacttodo,contacts WHERE contacttodo.contacts_id = contacts.ID AND YEAR(reminder) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(reminder) = MONTH(CURDATE())ORDER BY contacttodo.reminder ASC"; 
} 

elseif 

($_GET['reminder'] == 'thisquarter') {     
$thisquarter = date('Y-m-d');     
$query = "SELECT * FROM contacttodo,contacts WHERE contacttodo.contacts_id = contacts.ID AND YEAR(reminder) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND QUARTER(reminder) = QUARTER(CURDATE())ORDER BY contacttodo.reminder ASC"; 
} 

elseif 

($_GET['reminder'] == 'thisyear') {     
$thisyear = date('Y-m-d');     
$query = "SELECT * FROM contacttodo,contacts WHERE contacttodo.contacts_id = contacts.ID AND YEAR(reminder) = YEAR(CURDATE()) ORDER BY contacttodo.reminder ASC"; 
} 

else {     

$today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today'));     
$query = "SELECT * FROM contacttodo,contacts WHERE contacttodo.contacts_id = contacts.ID  AND contacttodo.reminder = '$today' ORDER BY contacttodo.reminder ASC";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from your question, this should help you get going.

Change your link to

```
<a href="/backend/followup/followup.php?reminder=week">Week</a>
```

and code to

```
if($_GET['reminder'] == 'week') {
    $week = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last sunday'));
    $query = "SELECT * FROM contacttodo,contacts WHERE contacttodo.contacts_id = contacts.ID AND contacttodo.reminder BETWEEN '$week' AND '$week' + INTERVAL 6 DAY ORDER BY contacttodo.reminder ASC";
} else {
    $today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today'));
    $query = "SELECT * FROM contacttodo,contacts WHERE contacttodo.contacts_id = contacts.ID AND contacttodo.reminder = '$today' ORDER BY contacttodo.reminder ASC";
}

/* Code to execute query and print results */
```

Comment: works like a charm! Thanks! How would I also add in Month and Quarter?

Comment: Just add more clauses. `elseif reminder == month`, `elseif reminder == quarter` and with respective code for that.

Comment: I got that part, just not sure what the string is for all in current month and all in current quarter...I think month is `YEAR(reminder) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(reminder) = MONTH(CURDATE())` how does one calculate current quarter?

Comment: Quarter - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_quarter

Comment: do you know why my $lastweek would not be working? I've updated my code.

Comment: MySQL BETWEEN works with `min` and `max` values, in that order. So for your `$lastweek` you'll need to exchange the arguments to MySQL BETWEEN.